# Arraylist error in class in my Android

Tags: java, android

I have created two class. One of which has reference to another:

```
public class SCHOOL {

private String schoolid;
private String schoolname;
private List<STUDENT> students;

}

//getters and setters for schoolid and schoolname;


public void setStudents(List<STUDENT> students) {
    this.students = students;
}


public List<STUDENT> getStudents() {
    return this.students;
}

public void addStudent(String names, String age) {
    STUDENT student = new STUDENT();
    student.setNames(names);
    student.setAge(age);
    students.add(student);

}


public class STUDENT {

private String names;
private String age;



public String getNames() {
    return names;
}

public void setNames(String names) {
    this.names = names;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}
}
```

The following is my main class:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final String tag = "Tag Activity";
    List<STUDENT> studentList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SCHOOL school = new SCHOOL();
    school.setStudents(studentList);
    List<STUDENT> students = school.getStudents();


    school.addStudent("kent", "43");
    school.addStudent("Winnie", "42");
    school.addStudent("Dennis", "41");

    studentList.add((STUDENT) students);
    Log.d(tag, String.valueOf(studentList));
    .......
```

The following is my error log from logical:

> 11-01 21:25:24.348 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4cb4b20)
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.spidey.jsontosql, PID: 3049
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.spidey.jsontosql/com.example.spidey.jsontosql.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.spidey.jsontosql.SCHOOL.addStudent(SCHOOL.java:50)
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.spidey.jsontosql.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>   11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>   11-01 21:30:25.020 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3049 SIG: 9

I try to input data using my addStudent method but the program crashed.  Is there something wrong in my code?  Please help me to correct..

Comment: Where do you declare (and *initialize*) `studentList`?

Comment: What error shows up when it crashes?

Comment: In my onCreate class in the main activity.

Comment: You've shown us 9 lines of code for `onCreate`.  Which of those causes the error?  `onCreate` calls `super.onCreate`.  What are you doing in `AppCompatActivity`?  Convert this into an actual [mcve].

Comment: Instead of 'List<STUDENT> studentList;' use 'List<STUDENT> student list = new ArrayList<STUDENT>()'.   Your list is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is:

```
studentList.add((STUDENT) students);
```

You cannot directly cast a List to a Student. Loop through each students in the list and add them.

```
for (Student student: studentList) {
    studentList.add(student);
}
```

Provide error logs next time

Comment: change "private List<STUDENT> students;"
of the School class to: "private List<STUDENT> students = new ArrayList<>();"

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a few brackets. I agree with Daniel above. The 'for each' loop should work.

Answer (score 0):

Show me code block above or log of IDE (logcat)
I think error is NullPointerEx...,

```
school.setStudents(studentList);
```

studentList is null or not init before used?

Comment: my program crash when it reaches "school.addStudent("kent", "43");".  What is the proper way to add student in my case?...

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException 11-01 21:25:24.360 3049-3049/com.example.spidey.jsontosql E/AndroidRuntime: at com.example.spidey.jsontosql.SCHOOL.addStudent(SCHOOL.java:50)

You understand? school.setStudents(studentList);  
studentList is NULL , follow my answer.
Replace 'school.setStudents(studentList);' with  school.setStudents(new List<STUDENT>);

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the actual code you are looking at. You are adding students to the SCHOOL and trying to get back the complete list of students.

```
`.....
SCHOOL school = new SCHOOL();
school.setStudents(studentList);


school.addStudent("kent", "43");
school.addStudent("Winnie", "42");
school.addStudent("Dennis", "41");

studentList = school.getStudents();;
Log.d(tag, String.valueOf(studentList));
.......`
```